# Probability with replacement - binomial distribution and combinatorics with replacements seem to give different answers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-distribution

I have come across a question about probabilities with replacement, and I would like to take a combinatorics approach to the question; however, it has failed, and I would like to know if I am doing something wrong. So let me first explain the question:

There are five balls with different colors: red, green, blue, white, black. The question is what is the probability of drawing exactly two red balls **with replacement**.

I know the answer is:

$$\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2 \cdot \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^3 \cdot {5 \choose 2} = \frac{128}{625}$$

since there is a $\frac{1}{5}$ chance of choosing a red ball and $\frac{4}{5}$ chance of not choosing a red ball. The order does not matter as well so multiply it by $5 \choose 2$. This explanation makes sense and it is in agreement with binomial distribution.

Now there is another approach as well, which is the one that gives me the wrong answer.

$$P(\text{exactly 2 red balls}) = \frac{\text{number of ways of drawing exactly 2 red balls from 5 draws}}{\text{total number of ways of drawing 5 balls with replacement}}$$

For finding the total number of ways of drawing 5 balls with replacement, we have 5 choices for each draw so we $5^5$ in total. Now to find the number of ways of drawing exactly $2$ red balls from $5$ draws, I think we can use the formula for drawing with replacement which is given by

$$n+k-1 \choose k$$

So we can choose $2$ red balls in ${5+2-1 \choose 2} = {6 \choose 2}$ and the remaining $3$ balls could be chosen in ${5+3-1 \choose 3} = {7 \choose 3}$. When we put everything together, we will get

$$\frac{{6 \choose 2}\cdot {7 \choose 3}}{5^5} = \frac{21}{125}$$

We can see the two answers do not match. So my question is what went wrong in my approach? Have I calculated number of ways of drawing exactly $2$ red balls from $5$ draws wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k}$$
counts the number of ways of selecting $k$ objects selected from $n$ types of objects with repetition.  However, these selections are not equally likely to occur.  There is only one way to select a red ball on each of the five draws.  However, there are $5! = 120$ ways to select one red, one green, one blue, one white, and one black ball.

As angryavian has already pointed out, there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select the two positions for the red balls and each of the remaining positions can be filled in four ways, so the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{5}{2}4^3$$
yielding the probability of selecting exactly two reds
$$\Pr(\text{exactly two reds}) = \frac{\dbinom{5}{2}4^3}{5^5} = \frac{128}{625}$$
when five balls are selected with replacement from the five balls of different colors, which, as angryavian has pointed out, agrees with the answer you obtained using the Binomial distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it is starting to make more sense. These two follow-up questions could help me understand it better:
1) If the question had asked "in how many ways can we choose two balls with repetition?" then the answer would have been $6 \choose 2$, right? 
2) Just to make sure I understand it correctly, in your answer there is a factor of $1^2$ because of two red balls, right? We just don't write it because it is equal to $1$. and if so how could we change the question so the base $1$ changes to another number greater than $1$?

Comment: The number of ways of selecting two balls with repetition is indeed $\binom{6}{2}$ since there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select two different color balls and five ways to select two balls of the same color.  Again, they are not equally likely to occur.  There is only one way to select two red balls, but there are two ways to select a blue ball and a green ball since you could first select a blue ball, then a green ball or vice versa.

Comment: You are also correct about the unstated factor of $1^2$.  An example of a question in which the base would change would be finding the probability of selecting exactly two aces when selecting five cards with replacement from a standard deck.  There are $52^5$ possible selections.  There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select two of the five positions for the aces, four ways to fill each of those positions since there are four suits, and $48$ ways to fill each of the three remaining positions with a card that is not an ace, giving the probability $$\frac{\binom{5}{2}4^248^3}{52^5}$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The card example made it even more clear!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably revisit where you found the $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ formula and what exactly it is counting; I suspect you are misusing it.

In the second approach the numerator should be $\binom{5}{2}$ (choose which two of the five draws were red) times $4^3$ (choice of color for the the non-red draws) which matches the first approach.

Comment: That formula counts the number of ways we wish to select $k$ objects of $n$ distinct objects with repetition. Isn't this correct?
In this question, we want to count in how many ways can we select $2$ red balls out of $5$ balls with repetition. I understand I might be wrong in phrasing it this way. Please point out where is my flaw. Thank you!